# Probability of birthdays on a specific day problem

Tags: statistics

Here's a basic stats problem that is bugging me. If there is equal probability of someone being born on any day of the year, then what is the chance that a randomly chosen person would have been born in January? Logically and intuitively I'd say 31/365, but this is not correct. The answer is 124/1461, and I cannot see how this is found. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Its a problem in a book and the answer at the back is 124/1461...no explanation, just the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over 4 years, there are usually $$4\times 365 + 1=1461$$
days (+1 because one of these four years is a leap year).  Of these, $$4\times 31=124$$
are days in January.  Hence, the probability you seek is roughly $124/1461$.  I say roughly because [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) are not exactly every 4 years.  Some century years (like 1900) are not leap years.

Comment: The proper way would be to note the calendar repeats on 400 year cycles and compute it over that.

Comment: Right, except that this assumes the Gregorian calendar for all time, forwards and backwards.  In fact it's only been in place for less than 500 years, and will likely be replaced due to its imperfections, sometime in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that seems to be it...didnt even cross my mind to take into account leap year and other details (the problem doesnt even mention to do so)...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Leap year.  Although even then the answer is not right due to the century rules.

Comment: Lol!!...ok...thats going outside of the box. That seems oddly silly to require accounting for leap years and other nuances of time (especially without mentioning it in the problem), but perhaps that's just me. Thanks!